# What is the total number of Bitcoin transactions processed so far?

Tags: blockchain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many transactions have been included into the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5564/how-many-transactions-have-been-included-into-the-blockchain)

The question explains itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my blockchain dump there are 10'876'856 transactions with at least 1 confirmation as of block 21'5753. That is excluding double spends and memorypool not yet confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

You can chek this and other statistics in:
http://blockchain.info/

With the available data, the simplest way is taking the number of blocks:
http://blockchain.info/q/getblockcount
and the average number of transactions per block:
http://blockchain.info/q/avgtxnumber
and multiply them. As I'm writing I get 215749*238=51348262 transactions.

The daily number of transactions is also online:
http://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions?showDataPoints=true&timespan=&show_header=true&daysAverageString=1&scale=0&address=

You could write some code to count the transactions directly from you local copy of the blockchain, but if you want a fast figure the links I've written are enough.

Comment: Average transactions per block is probably computed with a sliding window. The average has not been stable since the genesis block. It was probably much lower during the first year. I suppose 51M transactions is only an upper bound.

Comment: You are right. Counting the transactions the number is much smaller.